# Angular 4 reactive forms disable input field not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a root component and a child modal component, whenever I click on open modal button from root component, based on some value I either disable or enable a particular field in the reactive form. It looks like with my approach I am unable to disable the input box in the UI.

NOTE: I am using ngPrime modal component here

root.component.html:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" (click)="rateLimitingCRUDModal.openModal()">
  <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Create Rate Limiter
</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" (click)="rateLimitingCRUDModal.openModal(rateLimiter)" tooltip="Edit" container="body">
  <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
</button>

<app-rate-limiting-crud #rateLimitingCRUDModal (onSubmit)="getAllAPIThresholds()"></app-rate-limiting-crud>
```

modal.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-rate-limiting-crud',
  templateUrl: './rate-limiting-crud.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rate-limiting-crud.component.scss']
})
export class RateLimitingCrudComponent {
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private rateLimiterSvc: RateLimitingService,
              private toaster: ToastrService) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  public openModal(rateLimiter?: RateLimiter): void {
    this.isCreateRateLimiter = !rateLimiter;
    this.rateLimiter = rateLimiter;
    this.createForm(rateLimiter);
    this.rateLimitingCRUDModal.show();
  }

  createForm(rateLimiter?: RateLimiter): void {
    this.rateLimiterCRUDForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      account: [rateLimiter ? rateLimiter.account : null, Validators.required],
      threshold: [rateLimiter ? rateLimiter.threshold : null, Validators.required],
      granularity: [rateLimiter ? rateLimiter.granularity : '', Validators.required]
    });

    this.isCreateRateLimiter ? this.rateLimiterCRUDForm.get('account').enable() : this.rateLimiterCRUDForm.get('account').disable();
    // Observable.timer(0).subscribe(() => {
    //     this.isCreateRateLimiter ? this.rateLimiterCRUDForm.get('account').enable() : this.rateLimiterCRUDForm.get('account').disable();
    // });
  }
}
```

This line 
`this.isCreateRateLimiter ? this.rateLimiterCRUDForm.get('account').enable() : this.rateLimiterCRUDForm.get('account').disable();` doestn't work.
The commented line works for me.
Not sure, what wrong I am doing here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you `console.log(this.isCreateRateLimiter)` on the beginning of **createForm()** method, does it log the value as intended?

Comment: Initially it is just declared. But when the method `openModal` is called, then `this.isCreateRateLimiter` is set based on the argument. Then `createForm` is called and we build a form based on that value. It looks like, the reactive form field is disabled but the DOM doesn't render it as disabled input.